# UITabBarController with Hamburger menu/ Left sliding menu

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, hamburger-menu

I have an app with UITabBarController set as root controller. I need to have a hamburger menu no matter on which tab the user is. The question is - how to structure the app so that I don't have to repeat the hamburger menu code for every view controller - is there a way to do that? Only the gestures handling for opening and hiding the menu are around 100 lines of code. After a table view is added for the items in the hamburger menu I imagine it's going to be twice as that. Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another `View Controller` as a `parent view controller` and adding the `UITabBarController` as a `child view controller` to it. Then I added the `Hamburger menu` to the `parent view controller` and set `screenEdgePanGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false` for the gesture that opens the menu. On start of the gesture (`state .began`) I am setting the `isHidden property` of the menu view to `false` and call `view.bringSubviewToFront(self.menuView)` to have the menu over the views in the current tab.